# Access data / Structure data in ReactJS / Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a little bit losted coming from Rails to React/Firebase. I have the following realtime database structure. As you can see, a product can have a brand and multiple sellers.

If a brand is `true`, i'd like to get / display the brand contents on my page (the avatar, name, link etc.). Same for the sellers.

Right now, if i try to display the brand content, i get "true" when i'd like an object containing the infos i've stored in `brands` or `sellers`.

So i'd like for example to be able to do something like this :
`<p>{this.props.brands.name}</p>` (it can only have one brand for now)

As for the sellers i'd like for example to be able to do something like this :

```
this.state.sellers.map((seller) =>
  <div>
    <img src={seller.avatar} />
    <p>{seller.name}</p>
  </div>
);
```

Here is my firebase realtime database structure (json) :

```
{
    "products": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Nike HyperAdapt 1.0",
            "tagline": "Self-lacing running shoes",
            "releaseDate": "20.08.2020",
            "brands": {
                "Nike": true
            },
            "thumbnail": "/img/thumbnails/nike-hyperadapt-thumbnail.jpg",
            "media": "/img/media/nike-hyperadapt-media-01.jpeg",
            "isRaffle": true,
            "description": "Nike HyperAdapt 1.0 is Nike's first line of shoes that can lace themselves, thanks to an internal cable system comprised of fishing line and a pressure sensor located in the sole that responds to the weight of your foot as you move with an algorithmic pressure equation.",
            "upvote": "169",
            "sellers": {
                "Shop 01": true,
                "Nike": true
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Puma Fi",
            "tagline": "Self lacing shoes by Puma",
            "releaseDate": "22.08.2020",
            "brands": {
                "Puma": true
            },
            "thumbnail": "/img/thumbnails/puma-fi-thumbnail.jpg",
            "media": "/img/media/puma-fi-media-01.jpeg",
            "isRaffle": true,
            "description": "The technology platform Fit Intelligence (Fi) is designed to automate and finetune performance for our footwear. The very first Fi footwear style is a self-lacing training shoe made for workouts and light running.",
            "upvote": "88",
            "sellers": {
                "Shop 01": true,
                "Puma": true
            }
        }
    },
    "brands": {
        "Nike": {
            "name": "Nike",
            "avatar": "/img/brands/nike-logo.png",
            "link": "https://www.nike.com/fr",
            "products": {
                "1": true
            }
        },
        "Puma": {
            "name": "Puma",
            "avatar": "/img/brands/puma-logo.png",
            "link": "https://eu.puma.com/fr/fr/home",
            "products": {
                "2": true
            }
        }
    },
    "sellers": {
        "Shop 01": {
            "name": "Shop 01",
            "avatar": "/img/sellers/shop-01-logo.png",
            "link": "https://www.shop-01.com/",
            "products": {
                "1": true,
                "2": true
            }
        },
        "Nike": {
            "name": "Nike",
            "avatar": "/img/sellers/nike-store-logo.png",
            "link": "https://www.nike.com/fr/launch",
            "products": {
                "1": true
            }
        },
        "Puma": {
            "name": "Puma",
            "avatar": "/img/sellers/puma-logo.png",
            "link": "https://eu.puma.com/fr/fr/home",
            "products": {
                "2": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**
here is what the component that's supposed to show the data looks like :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProductPopup from './ProductPopup';

class ProductItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      productPopupStatus: false,
    };
  }

  showProductPopup = () => {
    this.setState({ productPopupStatus: true });
  };

  hideProductPopup = () => {
    this.setState({ productPopupStatus: false });
  };

  renderUpvoteBtn() {
    return (
      <div className="upvote-btn_wrapper">
        <a className="upvote-btn" href="#">
          <span className="upvote-counter">
            <i className="fas fa-sort-up"></i>
            <span>{this.props.upvote}</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderInfoSession() {
    return (
      <section className="product-item-info">
        <span>
          <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
        </span>
        <p>{this.props.tagline}</p>
        <div className="product-item_meta-shadow"></div>
      </section>
    );
  }

  renderMeta() {
    return (
      <div className="product-item_meta">
        <a href="#">
          // SHOW ASSOCIATED BRAND AVATAR AND NAME
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li className="product-item">
        {this.renderUpvoteBtn()}

        <a href="#" onClick={this.showProductPopup} className="product-item_content">
          <img className="product-item-media" src={this.props.media} />
          {this.renderInfoSession()}
        </a>

        {this.renderMeta()}
        <ProductPopup status={this.state.productPopupStatus} hidePopup={this.hideProductPopup} />
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductItem;
```

Comment: The solution is likely to use `Object.keys()` on the `brands` you get from the database. Please edit your question to show your current code that loads the brands and displays them. Only by seeing your current code can we help you fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're getting "true" because your brand name is a boolean. I think it might help by having your brand listed like:

```
brand: {
   name: "Nike"
}
```

As far as your sellers, I feel that listing them in an array rather than an object would be better as well. You'll only be getting "true" because those values are boolean.

Is there a reason you wanted "sellers" to be an object? If not I would make it an array with objects that hold the info you need.

```
brands: [
    {name: "Brand1", img: "imgsource1"},
    {name: "Brand2", img: "imgsource2"}
]
```

Comment: Right now if i do `{this.props.brands}` in my component, it returns for example ""Nike": true" . Now if for example the brand "Nike" is `true` in the product, i'd like to get the "Nike" brand infos from "brands"

Comment: The way OP currently stores `brands` is the idiomatic way to reflect a mathematical **set** in Firebase Realtime Database. As the keys in a node are by definition unique, using the structure in the question automatically ensures that each brand can be present only once. Storing them in an array will remove that automatic guarantee.

Comment: Ah, I see. It seems I did not fully understand the original question. Thank you for your feedback! So would you be able to use an "if" statement then just a "for-in" loop to cycle through the keys?

Comment: I have added the component where i'm trying to display the data if it helps..